# How to avoid copying when emitting object from separate thread using Qt/C++?

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt, c++11, memory

My goal: pass an object generated by a child thread to the main program thread, where it is read, copying it as few times as possible.

**What Works**

An object owned by the child thread, with this field as intermediate store:

```
private:
   cv::Mat rgb;
```

A simple getter method for that field:

```
cv::Mat freenect2_pipe::take_rgb(){
    return this->rgb;
}
```

Using both of the above when emitting the object to the main thread:

```
    std::vector<cv::Mat> images;
    while (!stop_requested && !pause_requested
            && rgbd_camera.Capture(images)
            ) {
        rgb = images[0];
        emit rgb_frame(take_rgb());
    }
```

Signal definition:

```
    void rgb_frame(const cv::Mat& image);
```

**What Does Not Work**

-emitting (a)  `rgb_frame(images[0])`, (b) `rgb_frame(rgb)`, or (c) rgb_frame(locally_created_copy_of_frame).

**Where/How Does it Fail?**

Segfaults when trying to read from the generated object (in this case, an OpenCV matrix).

*How do I achieve the goal?*s

**Additional Information**

1) The `images` array above is generated in a third, non-qt thread which is launched by the child thread. This happens in third-party code I cannot modify.

2) The segfault behavior is consistent whether I use QThreads or C++11 threads (probably, both use pthread in the background on my platform). When using C++11 threads directly, I create my own intermediate shared buffer. Hence (void) is emitted, but the main thread pops the object from the shared buffer on que. However, the read fails exactly at the same place.

[Edit]
Slot definition: `void tmp_display_rgb2(const cv::Mat& rgb);`

Comment: where is your slot definition?

Comment: see http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/signalsandslots.html on signals and slots

Comment: What exactly do I need to look into in the Signals & Slots reference?

Comment: you need to read the whole thing or at least skim through the code example.   You have little set up here.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand. The code works perfectly without copying when the emitter object is not in a separate thread. I went through the code examples. I don't see anything there (that I am not already using) that is related to controlling thread-shared memory.

Comment: Ok, I seem to have (partially) solved the issue. For one, ```rgb = images[0];``` does not actually copy the matrix. Taking a look at the assignment operator of OpenCV Mat class, it seems like it functions like a shared_ptr, and simply updates the number of user references without copying the data. The general solution, then, is to emit a std::shared_ptr<some_data_type> (tested, works). However, this does not avoid the function call (in this case, ```take_rgb()```), which I would like to avoid as well if possible. I will sleep on it and perhaps modify the question.

Comment: In the general case Qt solves this problem through the use of implicit sharing (http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/implicit-sharing.html), which is an implementation of _copy-on-write_ semantics.

Comment: Look at the project [qt-opencv-multithreaded](https://code.google.com/p/qt-opencv-multithreaded/), in particular the [classes](https://code.google.com/p/qt-opencv-multithreaded/source/browse/#svn%2Ftrunk%2Fsrc)  `ProcessingThread` and `SharedImageBuffer`.

Comment: Thank you, will take a look at both of these ASAP.

Comment: @Miki, good call, but in fact, my C++11 thread implementation discussed above was originally based on qt-opencv-multithreaded. I finally found the source of the problem there. It works with individual cv::Mat objects, since their reference counters are updated in the buffer and later accessed from the consumer thread. Similar semantics fail on, say, vectors of cv::Mat objects, since whereas the vector may be copied, the reference counters of "Mats" within the array are decremented. The data is deallocated as soon as the new batch arrives.

Answer (score 0):

There are two general solutions.

#1 and #2 minimize copying, but only #2 minimizes memory allocations.

Solution 1: recreate a new shared_ptr and reallocate the desired data item within it on each run through the loop. Use a buffer shared between threads to store the intermediate result.

```
while (playback_allowed
    && rgbd_camera.Capture(*images)) {

    this->buffer->push_back(images); //push onto the buffer

    emit frame();
    images = hal::ImageArray::Create(); //re-initialize the shared pointer
}
```

Solution 2 (theoretical): at the source of data acquisition, create a swap buffer that swaps between two memory locations. The source should write to only one of those at a time in the equivalent of the `Capture` method above, return a pointer to the location, and swap location at next iteration. If all is set up correctly, the producer thread will block before the Capture dares to overwrite the location being consumed/processed.

I the best I could do was to use solution #1, since I did not have the freedom to modify/override/replace the `Capture` method, which always re-allocates the contents of `images`. I went with a pure C++11 thread solution, using signal/slot as a handshake, and tested with two buffer implementations: one using locks and one using optimistic re-tries.

In theory, QThreads can also be used, and the buffer could possibly be replaced with the implicit queue provided by the Qt signal/slot mechanism,   which would require the entire shared_ptr to be emitted.